# Как сделать, чтобы функция могла использовать как callback, так и async?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, callback

Имею библиотеку, которая поддерживает callback.

Вот пример функции для нее:

```
import fs from "fs";

removeFile(req, file, cb) {
    fs.unlink(file.path, cb);
};
```

По всему приложению использую async/await:

```
import {promises as fs} from "fs";

    async removeFile(filePath) {
        return await fs.unlink(filePath);
    };
```

Можно ли из этих двух сделать одну универсальною, с целью лаконичности?

Вот моя попытка, идентичны ли они, не сломаю ли я библиотеку, что работает на callback?

```
import {promises as fs} from "fs";
import fsCb from "fs";

    async removeFile(filePath, cb = false) {
        if (cb) {
            return fsCb.unlink(filePath, cb)
        }
        return await fs.unlink(filePath);
    };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так как большинство функций с обратными вызовами ничего не возвращают, то вряд ли опциональный возврат Promise может что-то сломать, если и ваши функции с колбеками возвращали `undefined`.

Разве что `return await` обычно считается излишней работой: нет смысла дожидаться результата Promise, чтобы сразу опять облечь его в Promise (ведь любая асинхронная функция возвращает Promise). Достаточно будет `return fs.unlink(filePath);`. Тогда вам даже не нужно будет объявлять функцию как `async` (таким двойным функциям не обязательно быть `async`, если они не используют `await`: при отсутствии колбека, они могут просто возвращать `new Promise()`, если нет чего-то готового, возвращающего Promise).

Хотя, если подумать, есть один возможный способ что-то сломать: если раньше при отсутствии колбека возникала ошибка, а теперь её не будет — тогда пользователь, который будет работать со старым интерфейсом и случайно забудет колбек (но не будет ждать Promise), может не получить сообщения об ошибке и не сможет понять, что не так. Так что лучше, наверное, перестраховаться и выпустить новую версию библиотеки как semver major.

Comment: @nörbörnën минус за то, что ответ не отговаривает автора вопроса писать две разные реализации для каждой функции.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, отговори автора! =)

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение. Я тоже считаю, что альтернативное ответ или критический комментарий вместе с минусом лучше чем минус без них) Отговаривать не стану) Во-первых, мне кажется, что автор спрашивал не об этом. Во-вторых, боюсь, что я не совсем понимаю критику: автор как раз сомневался, стоит ли ему делать две разные реализации, а я отвечал на вопрос, не сломает ли одна реализация что-то. В-третьих, я искренне думаю, что у меня вряд ли больше опыта в построении таких архитектур, чем у автора вопроса или уважаемого критика)

Answer (score 4):

Немного добавлю к [ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1233672) уважаемого [vsemozhebuty](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/321883/vsemozhebuty).

Если бы мне пришлось писать современную библиотеку `unicornlib`, которую нужно было бы расширить таким вот применением callback-ов то я, наверное, сделал бы сиблинг-библиотеку `unicornlib-legacy` и там заворачивал бы асинхронные вызовы в вызовы колбеков.

Если совсем нет выбора, то *не вмешивался бы в бизнес-логику самой функции*. Сколько разного кода нужно дописать для поддержки "cb | promise" можно посмотреть на примере [функции pipeline](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/blob/4c57ac2bbe8cbc8afab70a67d92f4cbf4748f153/lib/output.js#L838) из библиотеки sharp.

Думаю, я бы пошёл через декорирование:

```
const { promises: fs } = require('fs');

function cbDecorator(fn) {
  return (...args) => {
    try {
      fn(...args);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
}

function fnDecorator(fn) {
  return (...args) => {
    let cb;
    if (typeof args[args.length - 1] === 'function') {
      cb = cbDecorator(args.pop());
    }
    return fn(...args).then((res) => {
      if (cb) {
        cb(null, res);
      }
      return res;
    }).catch((err) => {
      if (cb) {
        cb(err);
      }
      return Promise.reject(err);
    });
  };
}

async function removeFile(filePath) {
  return fs.unlink(filePath);
};

module.exports.removeFile = fnDecorator(removeFile);
```

Comment: Не вполне понятно зачем вам `process.nextTick`.

Comment: @PavelMayorov хочу в этом месте не ожидать выполнения cb, а пустить поток выполнения дальше

Comment: Но это странное поведение для функций, которым передан callback.

Comment: Кстати, зачем вам `Reflect.apply`?

Comment: @PavelMayorov 1. а как правильнее, синхронный запуск? 2. посмотрел как в nodejs заворачивается cb, думаю, разумно, thisArg применить, если он будет.

Comment: 1. Да, правильнее синхронный запуск. 2. Откуда он у вас будет, если вы его никогда не передаёте?

Comment: 1. хорошо (хотя я не вижу какое негативное влияние окажет такой асинхронный вызов cb) 2. задел на случай когда всё это используется в реальной библиотеке.

Comment: Задел на будущее без комментариев - путь к wtf-коду, который все боятся трогать, ибо не понимают что он делает...